# Jade, gulp-jade locals update

Tags: node.js, templates, pug, gulp

is any solution to update locals for jade templates for every build (even if watch jade file)?
Now, templates get data only on first build.

Comment: could you provide a relevant gulpfile? thanks.

Comment: [https://github.com/serheyShmyg/gulp-frontend/blob/master/Gulpfile.js](https://github.com/serheyShmyg/gulp-frontend/blob/master/Gulpfile.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. So here's your answer:

```
var fs = require('fs');

/*
 * Views
 */

gulp.task('views', function () {
  return gulp.src(o.views.src)
    .pipe(p.jade({
      locals: JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(o.views.data, 'utf8'))
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(o.dest));
});
```

**o.views.data** - path to json file, e.g. *'./src/data/data.json'*

Comment: What about grunt? Is there same solution for grunt?

Comment: "grunt.file.readJSON('app/src/data/data.json')" do the same thing for grunt, eg:

    jade: {
      build: {
        options: {
          pretty: true,
          data: grunt.file.readJSON('app/src/data/data.json')
        },
        files: [
          {
            expand: true,
            flatten: true,
            src: ['app/src/views/layouts/*.jade'],
            ext: '.html',
            dest: 'app/build'
          }
        ]
      }

Comment: I don't understand the problem? And what is the trick your solution, what I need to do instead to get the problem?